# Adding GIF as Watermark and Loop FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to add GIF over a video and continuously loop, but it animate once and stop on the video

`ffmpeg.exe -i "video.mp4" -i "ani.gif" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva444p,setsar=1,scale=80:80,rotate=PI/6:c=black@0:ow=rotw(PI/6):oh=roth(PI/6) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy -y output.mp4`

What is the solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg.exe -i "video.mp4" -ignore_loop 0 -i "ani.gif" -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva444p,scale=80:80,setsar=1,rotate=PI/6:c=black@0:ow=rotw(PI/6):oh=roth(PI/6) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:shortest=1" -codec:a copy -y output.mp4`

`ignore_loop` makes the GIF to loop as many times as set in the file's header, usually infinite.

The overlay normally runs till the end of both inputs, but that won't work here as the GIF will be looping indefinitely, so shortest option is enabled.

Comment: Hi, i have tried your command, this is working but facing two problem and didn't getting proper solution. 1 is my gif is transparent but when it is added overvideo that time gif is with white background,  i know "c=none" is for transparent backround but some how its not working. 2 problem is sometimes video not created its show only image with overlay gif with 0 seconds.

Any suggetion for this?